# How to set a background Image to a Button BUT STILL WORKS LIKE A NORMAL BUTTON (With Effects)?

Tags: android, android-button

I have been trying to achieve the **Normal android button effects** when the button is already set with a **background image**

But the problem is, once the **background is set, the button default nature is gone (shadows, clickable animation etc..)**

Can Someone please give me a working solutions for this?

Here's the code to my button

```
<Button style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:id="@+id/student"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/student"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.891" />
```

It looks amazing since I have set a background image but **It still looks like you have set an image to a `jLabel` in Java)**

How can I get the default button looks while keeping my background image intact?

Answer (score 0):

Button works by setting the background to a background with the elevation, shadows, ripple, etc.  To get the same behavior, you're going to need to set your background to a StateListDrawable that performs the ripple effect and puts the shadows and elevation effects with your image as the background inside of all that.  You can't just set the background to be your image, that will lose all of those features.  The easiest way to get that right is to look at the AOSP source code and find the drawable it uses, copy it to your project, and edit appropriately.

Basically in Android a Button is just a TextView with a special background preset.

Comment: Can you show me how to set **StateListDrawable** to a button?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `ImageButton` widget ? It has the same behaviour as a `Button` and  `ImageView` combined

Check this  [tutorial](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/imagebutton) to see how to work with it.

as mentionned in the official documentation

> Displays a button with an image (instead of text) that can be pressed or clicked by the user. By default, an ImageButton looks like a regular Button, with the standard button background that changes color during different button states. The image on the surface of the button is defined either by the android:src attribute in the  XML element or by the ImageView.setImageResource(int) method

Comment: But it doesn't look like a button with default button behaviours